# How to remove or hide an entity from Advanced Find?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm working on an entity called 'Give Feedback'. I want to give create permission for all users and give read permission for that entity where Feedback provider or Manager of the Feedback receiver is current user. I have created a dynamic view for this. But I want to hide that entity from Advanced Find because it allows the current user to see all the records for that particular entity.

Is there any way to do remove or hide an entity from Advanced Find without removing read permission from security roles?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the right privileges for your custom entity.

If you set the `Read` privilege as `User`, with Advanced Find they will be able to see only their own records.

Comment: Thanks for the response. but I want to give read permission to Manager of the Feedback receiver too. If I give read permission to User, Feedback receiver's manager cannot see that record. I have changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the property Searchable to No in Entity cutomizations.

Comment: Thanks for response! I think Searchable is available for field, we cannot set it for a entity. If I'm wrong could you please tell me how to set Searchable for an entity?